# Auto increment step number if element is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Attempting to auto increment step numbers for a form. Certain elements of the form may hide or show dependent on answers from above. 
**HTML**

```
<div class="confirmation-step">
    <span class="step-number"></span>
</div>
<div class="confirmation-step" style="display:none;">
    <span class="step-number"></span>
</div>
<div class="confirmation-step">
    <span class="step-number"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.confirmation-step').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':visible')) {
        //set variable stepNum
        //Haven't come up with anything good yet
    } else {}
    $(this).find('.step-number').html(stepNum);
});
```

**Sample Output**

```
<div class="confirmation-step">
    <span class="step-number">1</span>
</div>
<div class="confirmation-step" style="display:none;">
    <span class="step-number"></span>
</div>
<div class="confirmation-step">
    <span class="step-number">2</span>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$('.confirmation-step:visible .step-number').text(function(i) {return i+1;});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K8wWB/)